# Show data from PHP call to angularJS site

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Appreciate the help up-front!
Having trouble displaying the data I get back from PHP onto an AngularJS site.
I've looked at past threads on the topic, but none of them have helped.

What I can say is that the PHP/data I am getting back looks fine.  It just looks like there is a disconnect between maybe my JS file and my HTML file.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

//PHP CODE

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM insights");

$insightsArray = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{

$insightsArray[] = $row;

}

echo json_encode($insightsArray);

$conn->close();
```

//JS CODE

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);

myApp.controller('getInsights', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("/getInsights.php")
   .then(function(data){
       $scope.insightsArray = data;
   });

});
```

//HTML

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>Get Insight</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="getInsights">

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="insight in insightsArray">{{insight.insighttype}}</li>

</ul>
</div>
<script src="/angularJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller like this. You have to access the data property of your response.

```
myApp.controller('getInsights', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("/getInsights.php")
   .then(function(data){
       $scope.insightsArray = data.data;
   });

});
```